# Retrieving lines comparing columns from two files

Tags: awk

I'm trying to compare 2 tables and retrieve the matches based on two columns:

file 1

```
0.736   5   100 T
0.723   1   15  T
0.792   6   100 T
0.634   3   100 T
0.754   7   100 T
0.708   2   100 T
0.722   9   100 T
0.542   1   6   T
```

File 2

```
0.736   5   
0.634   3   
0.542   1
```

output

```
0.736   5   100 T
0.634   3   100 T
0.542   1   6   T
```

When I try this code it tells me that awk is not found, which doesnt make sense because I use awk regularly.. Could you help me out spotting the error here please?

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]=$0;next}{if(b=a[$1,$2]){print b}}' file1 file2> output
```

Comment: copy/paste the full, actual error message you're getting into your question. Try `awk 'BEGIN{print "hi";exit}'` - does that give you the same error? What does `which awk` (or `where awk` or `whence awk` or whatever other tool you happen to use to find a command in your PATH) tell you?

Comment: Its a simple `-bash: ​awk: command not found` error.Yeah the code you gave me works just fine. Every time I use awk it works just fine except with this code hah

Comment: strange I just ran your `awk` on my system `ubuntu 14.04` with no problems.  `GNU awk 4.0.1`

Comment: No worries then, must be the server. Gonna delete the question. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

you could use `grep`

```
grep -f file2 file1
```

or `awk`

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1];next}$1 in A' file2 file1
```

Hope this helps :)